# Can not open any folderBrowserDialogs in my second form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010 in C#. Basically, I have my first form with  my main code, then I have a second form set up where the user is prompted to enter multiple paths. However, only on form1 do any folderBrowserDialogs open. On form2, regardless of what I try so far, the button simply clicks and nothing changes. I have not altered anything but variables really from the one I use on form1 and it works just fine.

Here's a bulk of my code, it contains one of the folderBrowserDialog's that will not work. This is all form form2:

```
string mexPath;
string ausPath;
string canPath;
string chilPath;


public CultureInfo targetCulture1 = new CultureInfo("es-CL"); //Chili
public CultureInfo targetCulture2 = new CultureInfo("de-AT"); //Austria
public CultureInfo targetCulture3 = new CultureInfo("es-MX"); //Mexico
public CultureInfo targetCulture4 = new CultureInfo("fr-CA"); //Canada

PassoloU.PassoloApp app = new PassoloU.PassoloApp();

//Respective Language Paths
private void spanPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        mexPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

I have established 4 different folderBrowserDialog's in the design and I am not sure where to go from here.

EDIT: Thank you for the help. For some reason, adding "_1" to the end of each click events name allowed the dialog boxes to open. So now each reads "spanPath_Click_1", "germPath_Click_1", etc. I have no idea why this is an issue though, but it seemed to have solved my problem.

Comment: Is your spanPath_Click method attached to the Click event of the button you mentioned?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what value is returned from ShowDialog(), or that the code is being executed?  I've definitely had some copy/paste errors with button click event handlers and not registering them.

Comment: I run it in debug and everything executes fine

Comment: And yes MichaC, the spanPath_Click is assigned to that button.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Are you sure button name is spanPath in the second form ? you might have copied the code from form 1 but not the control names

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework 4. And yes, spanPath is correctly assigned to form2's button and nowhere else. Form1 contains a different one.

Comment: And I put a messagebox.show within one of them, so that when it is clicked it should show that instead, and nothing comes up.

Comment: Alright, for some reason when I double clicked on one of the buttons to have it pop up, it created a new code section with the same name, except now it has spanPath_Click_1 and that worked. Any idea why?

Comment: @NotThatDroid If you went to the Designer and added the `spanPath_Click` manually this issue occurs.  If you double click the button on the Form first, then copy the code over you are OK.  Ran into that in the past myself when duplicating some functionality.

Comment: How odd, I figured with as long as you called to it correctly it shouldn't be a problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your Form2 in Designer mode, select the button, go to properties and ensure the click event is attached to the button as MichaC mentioned.

I just tried to put together an example with two forms, Form1 with a label, FolderBrowserDialog, and a button. Form1 displays the browser dialog, and then the selected folder path is displayed in the label. If you click a button it displays Form2 with similar controls. Both the FolderBrowserDialogs worked just fine. Let me know if you need me to post it.